# Rebol url format bug

Tags: rebol

Cannot read

http://www.earnforex.com/blog/2010/08/forex-technical-analysis-for-week-0809%E2%80%940813/

how to encode the url to be able to read it with rebol ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it works for me:

```
print read to-url "http://www.earnforex.com/blog/2010/08/forex-technical-analysis-for-week-0809%E2%80%940813/"
```

Comment: Note that there is a non-ascii character in the url between "0809" and "0813". I think it is the probem. Otherwise it works with %xx style: print read http://www.google%2ecom

Answer (score 0):

Rebol should read any valid URL. Maybe it's redirecting, requires cookies, or some other requirement you've missed? Maybe the site blocks crawlers and assumes anything that isn't a browser is one?